# How to custom/override User.IsInRole in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm a newbine in ASP.NET Core, I see in the User property (in ClaimsPrincipal class) in my controller, it has User.IsInRole method, so how can I override it to call my service dependency and register in my application (I don't want to use extension method).

Comment: Give some code that you wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `User.IsInRole`, it is `ClaimsPrincipal` which is not registered as service, so, you could not replace `ClaimsPrincipal`, and you could not override `IsInRole`.

For a workaround, if you would not use extension method, you could try to implement your own `ClaimsPrincipal` and `Controller`.

- `CustomClaimsPrincipal` which is inherited from `ClaimsPrincipal`

  ```
  public class CustomClaimsPrincipal: ClaimsPrincipal
  {

  public CustomClaimsPrincipal(IPrincipal principal):base(principal)
  {

  }

  public override bool IsInRole(string role)
  {
      return base.IsInRole(role);
  }
  }
  ```
- `ControllerBase` to change `ClaimsPrincipal User` to `CustomClaimsPrincipal User`

  ```
  public class ControllerBase: Controller
  {
      public new CustomClaimsPrincipal User => new CustomClaimsPrincipal(base.User);
  }
  ```
- Change the `Controller` from inheriting `ControllerBase`.

  ```
  public class HomeController : ControllerBase
  {
         public IActionResult About()
  {
      ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";
      var result = User.IsInRole("Admin");

      return View();
  }
  ```
- Change the logic in `public override bool IsInRole(string role)` based on your requirement

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work with Authorize attribute of Controllers. To solve it use ClaimsTransformation (see another answer here)

Answer (score 11):

You can use ClaimsTransformation:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
    }
}

public class CustomClaimsPrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
{
    public CustomClaimsPrincipal(IPrincipal principal): base(principal)
    {}

    public override bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        // ...
        return base.IsInRole(role);
    }
}

public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var customPrincipal = new CustomClaimsPrincipal(principal) as ClaimsPrincipal;
        return Task.FromResult(customPrincipal);
    }
}
```

Controller method:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    // ...
}
```

Role checking by Authorize attribute will use your overrided IsInRole method

Comment: This is the true answer! Thank you @CheloweKot!

Comment: I tried this,  and it doesn't hit the breakpoint set in the overridden IsInRole method..  any idea why this may occur? Where at in the configureservices method should the add transient line be added? Does it matter?

Comment: @eaglei22, try look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67877152/iclaimstransformation-not-being-called